# Configuring XPM Extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, experience-manager, cme

I'm trying to install the XPM extension in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 (following the SDL Documentation) in my Tridion Web App and I'm not be able to get it.

I have a .NET Application for the Experience Manager configured in port 83 in my IIS and the OData service works fine, because it returns me a response when I call it (I can view his methods). At this moment, I have configured all like the manual recommends, and configured storage copying the file that I have in the Deployer section (Windows process).

`cd_storage_conf`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVER_NAME_NETOSONE" />
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TBUser" />
                    <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\ExperienceManager\bin\config\cd_licenses.xml"/>        
</Configuration>
```

`cd_deployer_conf`:

```xml
...
    <Queue>
        <Location Path="C:\tridion\incoming" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
    </Queue>
    <HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="524288000" Location="C:\tridion\incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
    <License Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\ExperienceManager\bin\config\cd_licenses.xml"/>
...
```

In my `cd_dynamic_conf` I have configured a publication and host:

```xml
<Publication Id="5">
    <Host Domain="localhost" Port="83" Protocol="http" Path="/es/"/>
    <Host Domain="localhost" Port="84" Protocol="http" Path="/es/"/>
</Publication>
```

Is this configuration OK?
Then, I have added the XPM extension into my site (HTML pages) in port 84, copying all the files that indicates the documentation, and replacing the `storage_conf` and `dynamic_conf` with the same files in the XPM Application that I have just mentioned. Is this configuration OK?

Finally, the configuration of target publication in the CME (on Session Preview tab):

1. Content Delivery Endpoint URL: `http://localhost:83/odata.svc/`
2. Web site Urls: `http://localhost:84/, http://localhost:83/`

Is it possible to use the same database (Tridion_Broker) to publish content from CME and share it with XPM? I think yes, but probably it could be the problem.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Before raise, a question maybe trying to research bit more research about your issue, there are a lot of questions and answers are out for this. The architecture of the SDL Tridion User Interface 2012 introduces a new ODATA web service, a new Session Wrapper Database

Comment: See here Nuno's answers here in this post might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133696/tridion-experience-manager-xpm-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglected to mention which version of SDL Web/Tridion you are using, so I'll assume you are using the latest, being SDL Web 8.5 (if you are using a different version, please **edit** your question and provide this information, it can be as simple as adding a tag with the version of Tridion/SDL Web).

According to the documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-7EF9873A-F2A2-4E17-A4E1-6209310F20B6, what you need is;

- Session-enabled Content Service
- Preview Service

Both of these can be installed as microservices, which are the easiest way to manage them. To install them, please follow the following information from the documentation:

- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-0CAB75CA-DB8D-4DB9-B836-1761D4230152
- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-68991189-44A8-4009-937E-28B5ECE463BF

## update

Since you now specified that the version you are using is SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, I'll update my answer (I'll leave the original answer in tact as that might come in handy for other people with a similar question).

*Let me first warn you that SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is currently in limited support and will run into extended support in November this year (2017), so you should really consider upgrading to a more recent version.*

Following the documentation http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7EF9873A-F2A2-4E17-A4E1-6209310F20B6 you will indeed need an Experience Manager Web service. The documentation has a quick start guide for this http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539

This web service should be a separate website, and not part of your staging website itself, as that makes it more complex to manage and configure.

Furthermore, make sure you follow all steps of the quickstart guide, so create new separate databases and use separate configurations for it. While the database itself is of a similar layout than the Broker database which you configure for the Deployer, it should not be the same database.

Answer (score 1):

For one of your questions, you need to have **diffrerent** databases for the content of the Tridion Broker, and the sessioned content for the Experience Manager.

You can't share the same database for Broker and XPM

*But as @Velmurugan commented before, there are a lot of issues that you can manage to research and try, before to raise a so general question.*